# Read XML stored in MSSQL 2014 database using text datatype

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I have a table called "project" with a column name "path" which has XML data stored as text (nvarchar(max)).

This is content for one of the rows under column "path",

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ProjectPerfoceSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Server>101.0.101.101</Server>
<Port>1625</Port>
</ProjectPerfoceSetting>
```

I want to get following output,

Server               Port
101.0.101.101        1625

Below is the query I am using and it returns null,

```
SELECT 
    CAST(path AS XML).value('declare namespace ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";(/ProjectPerfoceSetting/Server/@Text)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
FROM project
```

Can someone please suggest on what is wrong with above query. Thanks in advance.

Update

Somehow the query would return null for below XML data,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ProjectTFSSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://DT">
<Server>45.25.211.222</Server>
<Port>8080</Port>
</ProjectTFSSetting>
```

Query

```
Select A.[ProjectName]

      ,Server = B.XMLData.value('(ProjectTFSSetting/Server)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
      ,URL = B.XMLData.value('(ProjectTFSSetting/Url)[1]'  , 'varchar(200)')
 From [CxDB].[dbo].[Broadridge_Scans_View] A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast(Path as xml)) B
```

In addition, the column "path" also some text data stored. How do I access those in addition to parsing the XML data?

Now here is another scenario,

This is how table "project" looks like with below columns.

ID  Path

1  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectPerfoceSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Server>101.0.101.101</Server><Port>1625</Port></ProjectPerfoceSetting>`

2  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectGITSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><URL>http://test.com</Server><folder>/customer</folder></ProjectPerfoceSetting>`

3  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectTFSSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://DT"><Server>45.25.211.222</Server><Port>8080</Port></ProjectTFSSetting>`
4  some text not xml

Is it possible to get below output?

```
ID  Server                            Port
1   101.0.101.101                     1625
2   http://test.com                   /customer 
3   http://londbcntfs:8080/tfs/BCN/   8080
4   some text not xml
```

Comment: The xml for ID 2 is not correct.  Please review/update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to store XML data as xml.  However, by adding a CROSS APPLY (OUTER APPLY to show NULLs), it becomes a small matter to facilitate the conversion.

**Example (Added a second row to illustrate)**

```
Declare @Project table (ID int,Path nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @Project values
(1,'<ProjectPerfoceSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Server>101.0.101.101</Server><Port>1625</Port></ProjectPerfoceSetting>'),
(2,'<ProjectTFSSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://DT"><Server>http://londbcntfs:8080/tfs/BCN/</Server><Port>8080</Port></ProjectTFSSetting>')

Select A.ID
      ,Server = B.XMLData.value('(*/Server)[1]', 'varchar(200)')
      ,Port   = B.XMLData.value('(*/Port)[1]'  , 'varchar(200)')
 From @Project A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData = cast(replace(Path,'xmlns="','dummy="') as xml)) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Server                            Port
1   101.0.101.101                     1625
2   http://londbcntfs:8080/tfs/BCN/   8080
```

Comment: @codeninja Saw the edit.  root node ProjectTFSSetting vs ProjectPerfoceSetting .   How variable is your XML?

Comment: @codeninja last example also has xmlns  ... one moment for a fix

Comment: @codeninja it is a bit of a hack regarding the xmlns, but it works.  I also wild carded the root node

Comment: Thanks John. that worked! Can you please advise on one last question? I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

The supplied XML for ID 2 was not correct.

Small change to OUTER APPLY and IsNull()

You also need to learn how to format your questions better.

```
Declare @Project table (ID int,Path nvarchar(max))
Insert Into @Project values
(1,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectPerfoceSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><Server>101.0.101.101</Server><Port>1625</Port></ProjectPerfoceSetting>'),
(3,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectTFSSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://DT"><Server>45.25.211.222</Server><Port>8080</Port></ProjectTFSSetting>'),
(2,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><ProjectGITSetting xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><URL>http://test.com</URL><folder>customer</folder></ProjectGITSetting>'),
(4,'some text not xml')

Select A.ID
      ,Server = isnull(B.XMLData.value('(*/Server)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),isnull(B.XMLData.value('(*/URL)[1]', 'varchar(200)'),Path))
      ,Port   = isnull(B.XMLData.value('(*/Port)[1]'  , 'varchar(200)'),B.XMLData.value('(*/folder)[1]', 'varchar(200)'))
 From @Project A
 Outer Apply (Select XMLData = cast(replace(Path,'xmlns="','dummy="') as xml)) B
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Server  Port
1   101.0.101.101       1625
3   45.25.211.222       8080
2   http://test.com     customer
4   some text not xml   NULL
```